# System Idle Process occupying a specific port

Tags: python, windows, rabbitmq, port, basehttpserver

I'd like to ask about System Idle Process where it seems to be occupying a specific port that I'm using.

I'm suspecting this is the reason why my `BaseHTTPServer` python script that listens to requests sometimes randomly stops listening without any error messages**. When I use `netstat` in `powershell`, this is the result I get:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
      0       0       56          8                 0   0 Idle
    250      18    17896      25168      11.22  24832   2 python
```

The python script does have a `time.sleep()`. In a bat script meant to keep it alive if it is ever encounters an exception, it also have a timeout /t. Could these be the reason why?

I've only just encountered this error. Previously, there were no problems until now. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. `IIS` isn't using the port, and I don't have PBX installed in this machine.

If it matters, this script listens to requests then sends data to `RabbitMQ`, and it is using port 8088.

Comment: The idle process cannot do that because it consists only of one thread per CPU running a loop doing nothing. What's more likely is that the process ID associated with the socket is not set and it ends up as zero, and the `ProcessName` column helpfully tries to look up the name of process ID zero which is the idle process in normal circumstances. It may actually be a socket used by a kernel driver for example.

Comment: @CherryDT, the idle threads do much more than nothing; they're integral to checking power states, DPC dispatch queues, timers, and selecting the next ready thread to dispatch, but they certainly won't be doing anything with ports, so your guess is probably spot on.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I oversimplified probably.

Comment: By the way of course a rootkit may also cause this!

Comment: I'm assuming since the process doesn't interfere with ports, the python script randomly stopping to listen isn't affected by it then yes? It narrows down the problem. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're showing a PowerShell `get-process` output instead of the output from `netstat`.

Comment: That's an error on my part. Apologies!